# Don't understand how this recursive function is working

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, binary-tree, postorder

Recently I've done this function below to generate a binary tree nodes list by "Post Order" method:

```
def getNosPosOrdem(self):
    if self.root is not None:
        nodesList = []
        self.__getNosPosOrdem(nodesList, self.root)
        return nodesList
    else:
        return -1

def __getNosPosOrdem(self, nodesList, node):
    if node.leftNode is not None:
        self.__getNosPosOrdem(nodesList, node.leftNode)
    if node.rightNode is not None:
        self.__getNosPosOrdem(nodesList, node.rightNode)
    nodesList.append(node.value)
```

This basically (until the part I understood) goes to the last element from left and I supposed that I'll going to have problems with the continuation of the code verification to the next element (other nodes above, after reaching the bottom left one) — but surprisingly to me, it works.

The point is, I want to understand why the code is still checking the other nodes even though I didn't call it recursively when I added the bottom first node:

Result is: `[2, 6, 9, 17, 12, 5, 27, 40, 45, 36, 20]`.

Comment: Huh? You *are* making recursive calls, one for each child of the current node. It's after the recursive call *returns* (with `nodesList` appropriately modified) that you append the current node's value to the list as well.

Comment: This question is unclear - at least for me. We can't test it because the code example is incomplete and we're missing the call to the function.

Comment: @Matthias sorry, the list of entrance is [20,5,12,36,27,45,9,2,6,17,40]. It's a binary tree, let's abstract the rest of the code, it works but i can't understand how it can continue calling himself after reaching the last node from the left (and going to the others nodes)

Comment: @chepner thanks Chepner! I were looking at the functions and reference methods docs of Python and it's seems like the calls still running and filling the list as you told. I really appreciate that.

Comment: Also, `-1` is unnecessary and confusing as a return value. `[]` works perfectly well as the list of values for an empty tree.